# Python - Count the number of lines of an output

Tags: python

So I want to identify and count misspelled words.

I have managed to identify them, but it seems I cannot count them...
Please bear in mind I am new to Python.
I tried len, but it returned me the length of the word, and I tried count but I got nothing.

From the code below, I want to count the variable "wrong_words".

What am I doing wrong?

P.S:to be crystal clear, the misspelled words are 'hapenning', 'protugal'. And I want as output the sum of them, hence 2.

Thank you

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

spell = SpellChecker()

# find those words that may be misspelled
misspelled = spell.unknown(['something', 'is', 'hapenning', 'here', 'protugal'])

for word in misspelled:
    # Get the one `most likely` answer
    wrong_words = spell.correction(word)
    print(wrong_words)
```

Comment: Hi @Mig can you tell what does `spell.correction(word)` returns if the word is spelled correctly?

Comment: Hi @overflow95, it doesn't return anything. The spell.correction(word) only gets the misspelled words.

Comment: What you are expecting is number of misspelled words in `misspelled`? In the list given above it should be 2,right?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Just to be crystal clear, the words that are misspelled are 'hapenning' and 'protugal'. I will clarify the original post, thanks

Comment: You can create a count variable and then check if word is misspelled and then increase this count.
`count=0`
`for word in misspelled`:
      `if spell.correction(word):`
           `count+=1`

count will give you number of misspelled words.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Much appreciated.